# Wildcard subdomains with dnsmasq

Tags: dns, subdomain, wildcard, dnsmasq

I have a device that is already mapped to `domain.tld`. I now want to create a wildcard for all subdomains `*.domain.tld` so that they are mapped to the ip of `domain.tld`, too.
How do I do this with `dnsmasq`?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In the `dnsmasq.conf` file, add the line

```
address=/.domain.tld/192.168.0.1
```

But use the IP you actually want as that end bit

Comment: I would usually create a separate configuration file for each host and place it in the '/etc/dnsmasq.d/' directory.  The advantage to this is not having to deal with such a monolithic file when it comes time for maintenance.

Comment: @LukeA.Leber that sound even more tedious as finding the correct host file would be the same or even less "maintainable" as a line in a file. Then on top of locating the file you have to make the same edit(s).  More work.

Comment: See below: a leading dot is not a wildcard

Comment: but this can only add one record for a wilcard domain, how can i have multiple record?

Comment: Wildcards in dnsmasq works out of the box... `address=/domain.tld/192.168.0.1` domain.tld and also any subdomain e.g. sub.domain.tld will be translated to 192.168.0.1. So entering dot at the start of misleading. When we add entry `address=/another.domain.tld/192.168.0.255`  it will be translated to 192.168.0.255 but any not defined subdomain to 192.168.0.1

Answer (score 78):

While the accepted answer may have solved the author's problem, it is misleading as it suggests that the leading dot would match subdomains only, which is not true.

dnsmasq [ignores](http://thekelleys.org.uk/gitweb/?p=dnsmasq.git;a=blob;f=src/option.c;h=064ef62362903800463d242ac6905640f114987c;hb=74ea91531a5f0c6ad8c4bcc5f6bda55bf2c2acb1#l2390) any leading dots, so that

```
address=/domain.tld/192.168.0.1
```

is equivalent to

```
address=/.domain.tld/192.168.0.1
```

or even

```
address=/......domain.tld/192.168.0.1
```

As of now (dnsmasq v2.76), there is unfortunately no way to specify some things (`server`, `address`, `ipset`) for

- a single domain name only, i.e. domain name without its subdomains
- only for the subdomains of a domain name

The only thing you can do, is to specify something for a domain name and all its subdomain and have override it for specific subdomains, e.g.

```
address=/domain.tld/192.168.0.1
address=/sub.domain.tld/10.10.0.1
```

This single domain name only case, may be tackled with different options, such as `host-record`, `srv-record`, which may be sufficient in some cases, but certainly not in all. It won't work for example, if you really need to use the `server` or `ipset` option for a single domain name only.

Comment: Which version of dnsmasq supports overrides as stated above? I've got dnsmasq 2.76-g0007ee9 from Asus Merlin and it doesn't work

Comment: @Hengjie I just tested the overrides in the above example configuration with a build of the official 2.76 release of dnsmasq. I put the two lines in a temporary config file, executed `dnsmasq -p 5353 -k -C /tmp/dnsmasq.conf` and tested with `dig @127.0.0.1 -p 5353 sub.domain.tld`. Anyway I don't recall that overriding settings this way has been added in any particular version of dnsmasq. It should basically work with any dnsmasq version.

Comment: is it possible to do `address=.example/*/foo` ? doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @chovy You should probably ask a separate question. It is unclear, what you intend to do and what doesn't work. Something which I can definitely say is, that the wildcard in the address option is `#` not `*`.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like `address=localhost.*/127.0.0.1`? That is point any host with a subdomain of localhost to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai To the best of my knowledge, no it's not possible.

Comment: Is the order important? In the above example, what would `sub2.sub.domain.tld` resolve to?

Comment: @SebastianSchrader seems '#' can be used alone, not like #.example.com, right?

Comment: `#` is a special value handled by dnsmasq, that matches any domain, it can't be used as a wildcard for parts of a domain.

Comment: You can add all subdomains overrides to `dnsmasq-hosts` file and instruct `dnsmasq` to use this file with arg `-H`.

    -H, --addn-hosts=<file>
    Additional hosts file. Read the specified file as well as /etc/hosts. If --no-hosts is given, read only the specified file. This option may be repeated for more than one  additional hosts file. If a directory is given, then read all the files contained in that directory.

Comment: Wildcards in dnsmasq works out of the box... `address=/domain.tld/192.168.0.1` domain.tld and also any subdomain e.g. sub.domain.tld will be translated to 192.168.0.1. When we add entry `address=/another.domain.tld/192.168.0.255`  it will be translated to 192.168.0.255 but any not defined subdomain to 192.168.0.1