# How to configure wildcard subdomains for authoritative (auth) dnsmasq dns server?

Tags: dnsmasq

I have compiled `dnsmasq` v2.76 including support for running its authoritative dns server (NOAUTH removed in the Makefile).

[Wildcard subdomains with dnsmasq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313142/wildcard-subdomains-with-dnsmasq) is possible for the caching part of the server.

I have tried:

1. `host-record=*.domain.tld,1.2.3.4`
2. `host-record=.domain.tld,1.2.3.4`
3. `host-record=domain.tld,1.2.3.4`
4. `address=/domain.tld/1.2.3.4`

None of them return the expected answer for www.domain.tld.

How to configure a **wildcard A record** for the authoritative side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the to be released dnsmasq version 2.77 there will be a wildcard option for CNAME records.

That can be configured like these examples:

```
cname=*.domain.tld,domain.tld
cname=*.otherdomain.tld,host.even-another-domain.tld
```

Since [commit b637d7815da89b5fb04c27b1d9a361fe5b2622a0](http://thekelleys.org.uk/gitweb/?p=dnsmasq.git;a=commit;h=b637d7815da89b5fb04c27b1d9a361fe5b2622a0) Tue, 13 Dec 2016 18:44:11 +0200 there is support for CNAME wildcards.
[Commit 2.77test4](http://thekelleys.org.uk/gitweb/?p=dnsmasq.git;a=commit;h=62f9c0d47099f46cac941ce0ea103921999d244f) contains the latest addition to the wildcard code.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Upon your request a CNAME configuration example for dnsmasq version 2.77 has been appended.

Comment: Is that saying any subdomain of `domain.tld` maps to `domain.tld`? And could also be used like `domain.tld` mapping to `otherdomain.tld`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yes, the example is saying to map any subdomain of domain.tld to domain.tld, and **yes** mapping catch-all `*.domain.tld` to `host.otherdomain.tld` is also possible. At least for the case where `host.otherdomain.tld` is configured in the same dnsmasq.conf (Haven't test third-party auth. served `otherdomain.tld`)

Comment: However this like addr setting doesn't allow wildcards to appear in the middle right? I was looking for something like `localhost.*` to map to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [dnsmasq man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html), only some options are used to populate the data for authoritative zones:

> When dnsmasq is configured to act as an authoritative server, the following data is used to populate the authoritative zone.
>
> `--mx-host`, `--srv-host`, `--dns-rr`, `--txt-record`, `--naptr-record` , as long as the record names are in the authoritative domain.
>
> `--cname` as long as the record name is in the authoritative domain. If the target of the CNAME is unqualified, then it is qualified with the authoritative zone name.
>
> IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from /etc/hosts (and `--addn-hosts` ) and `--host-record` and `--interface-name` provided the address falls into one of the subnets specified in the `--auth-zone`.
>
> Addresses of DHCP leases, provided the address falls into one of the subnets specified in the `--auth-zone`. (If contructed DHCP ranges are is use, which depend on the address dynamically assigned to an interface, then the form of `--auth-zone` which defines subnets by the dynamic address of an interface should be used to ensure this condition is met.)
>
> In the default mode, where a DHCP lease has an unqualified name, and possibly a qualified name constructed using `--domain` then the name in the authoritative zone is constructed from the unqualified name and the zone's domain. This may or may not equal that specified by `--domain`. If `--dhcp-fqdn` is set, then the fully qualified names associated with DHCP leases are used, and must match the zone's domain.

In particular only `host-record`, hosts file entries and DHCP leases can generate A/AAAA records and the `--address` option is **not** taken into account. Unfortunately, the  `--address` option is the only way to specify A/AAAA responses for a domain and all its subdomains.

dnsmasq does not have a wildcard record feature known from other DNS servers like bind, as stated in [my answer to the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37449551/2350268).

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is no wildcard support for --server but there is for cname, host etc..